# JPA ManyToOne Relationship: foreign key not being stored in table of many side

Tags: jpa, save, many-to-one

The subordinate side of OneToMany relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="xxx_customer")
@XmlRootElement(name="Customer")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer implements Serializable {

   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="customer")
   private List<CreditCard> creditCards;


   public void addCreditCart(CreditCard creditCard) {

       creditCards.add(creditCard);
   }

}
```

The owning side of ManyToOne relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="xxx_credit_card")
@XmlRootElement(name="CreditCard")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CreditCard implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Call from OrderManager to create Customer and CreditCard records:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class OrderManager {

    @Inject
    @UserDatabase
    private EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void placeOrder(ShoppingCart cart) {

        try
        {
            Customer customer = cart.getCustomer();
            customer.addCreditCart(cart.getCreditCard());
            em.persist(customer);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ctx.setRollbackOnly();

            MessageUtil.addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
                    "Place Order", "Error placing order!");

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

The data is created in both tables but the customer_id field of the CreditCard table is null. It does not contain the id of the Customer record as expected.

Comment: The code shows you adding a creditCard to a customer, but as you mentioned, this relationship is subordinate to the CreditCard->Customer relationship.  Are you setting the creditCard's customer?  With out it, the foreign key won't be set.

Comment: I am using the same type relationship between Order and Customer with Order being the owning side. The customer_id column in the Order table is populated as expected

Comment: It won't unless you are adding the Customer to Order.  Possibly in in your customer.addOrder method, you are both adding the order to the collection and 'this' customer to the order.   JPA treats entities as POJO's and does not do relationship maintenance for you.

Comment: JPA does maintain the relationship lest I would have had to code:

em.persist(customer);
creditCard.setCustomerId(customer.getId());
em.persist(creditCard);

But this abbreviated version always worked with the primary keys of both tables and the foreign key being populated:

customer.setCreditCard(creditCard)
em.persist(customer);

You are on to something in that I am trying to establish a bidirectional relationship and perhaps, as you said, it doesn't work as I think it should. I will have to explore this line of thinking.

Comment: Your comments are incorrect. Set customer on the credit card as advised above and it will work.

Comment: @Alan Hay Your prescribed solution didn't work.

Comment: This is a basic mapping. If it isn't working maybe you should do some reading on the fundamentals.

Comment: @Chris Your suggestion that JPA does not do relationship maintenance was on the right track. More specifically, according to WikiBooks, "JPA does not maintain bi-directional relationships for you." Maybe this is the problem. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: @koque, thanks for the confirmation, though it isn't a maybe, it is.  If you don't set the owning side, the foreign key it controls wont get set.  And I wouldn't discount advice given on here, as you may not know their levels of expertise.  If you are going to say something didn't work, show what you did and the specifics behind what didn't work, such as logs etc, so that others can help you understand the problem.

Comment: @Chris Advice taken.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the bi-directional relationship you have to ensure that the update in one side updates the other side as well. It can be resolved through the "add" or the "set" methods like this :

Either you modify Customer class this (suggested solution, since you are using the add method in your manager code):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="xxx_customer")
@XmlRootElement(name="Customer")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer implements Serializable {

   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="customer")
   private List<CreditCard> creditCards;


   public void addCreditCart(CreditCard creditCard) {
       if(creditCard.getCustomer()!=this) creditCard.setCustomer(this);
       creditCards.add(creditCard);
   }

}
```

or modify the CreditCard Class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="xxx_credit_card")
@XmlRootElement(name="CreditCard")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CreditCard implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Customer customer;

    public setCustomer(Customer customer){
       if(!customer.getCreditCards().contains(this)) customer.getCreditCards().add(this);
       this.customer=customer;
    }
}
```

And now every time you update the customer field in CreditCard instance you have the list of credit cards updated in the other side or vice-versa.
You can modify both of the classes but you have to ensure that you don't get an infinite loop.